# CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED (tried System Default and WWDC suggestions already)

Tags: ios

I've already tried to check the trust levels on the certificates (making it System Default) and the WWDC cert is added as well.

Here is my log:

```
CodeSign /Users/brianhoffman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pop-aggtncikxgswfeeaurvvvpqmzlbw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pop.app
cd /Users/brianhoffman/Documents/iOS_Projects/Pop
setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "iPhone Developer: Brian Hoffman (XXXXXXXXX)" --resource-rules=/Users/brianhoffman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pop-aggtncikxgswfeeaurvvvpqmzlbw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pop.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/brianhoffman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pop-aggtncikxgswfeeaurvvvpqmzlbw/Build/Intermediates/Pop.build/Debug-iphoneos/Pop.build/Pop.xcent     /Users/brianhoffman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pop-aggtncikxgswfeeaurvvvpqmzlbw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pop.app

/Users/brianhoffman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pop-aggtncikxgswfeeaurvvvpqmzlbw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pop.app: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Any thoughts?